# How do i convert from integer to binary in standard_logic (no vector) in vhdl

Tags: binary, integer, vhdl

I am inputing into a seven segment display from a clock but the output right now from the clock is in integer. how do i convert it to binary?

```
    library ieee;
    use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
    use ieee.numeric_std.all;

    architecture behav of converter is 
    signal x : integer;
    signal xbin : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);

    begin  

    xbin <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(x, xbin'length));

    end behav;
```

Comment: Go ahead and post some of your code so we can better help.

Comment: alright sorry about that. done

Comment: Your code looks OK. What's your question?

Comment: aren't you looking instead for the signals to drive the 7  segment display? That's not plain binary... More like turn on the top segment is the value is 0 2 3 5 6 7 8 or 9, and so on!